# Can't save struct in custom UserDefaults - Error encode

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4

After I fill out my form I input everything in a NSDictionary.
All of my other items can save no problem if I comment this out.

One of them being category. I encode it but keep getting the error

`encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c80bbe40'`

Category Items is a subclass of `Codeable`.

Saving.

```
let playerDict : NSDictionary = [
  "category" : CategoryItems(name: categoryData[0].name, image: categoryData[0].image, type: categoryData[0].type),
]


   class PlayerModel: NSObject, NSCoding {

   var category: CategoryItems?

   init(json: NSDictionary) {
     if let category = json["category"] as? CategoryItems {
            self.category = category
     }
  }
}



required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
  if let category = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "category") as? CategoryItems {
            self.category = category
        }
}

func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
  if let category = self.category {
            aCoder.encode(category, forKey: "category")
        }
}
```

Model:

```
struct CategoryItems: Codable {
    var name : String
    var image : String
    var type : playerType
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that you can't use `NSCoding` with structs. Objects adopting `NSCoding` must be a sub**class** of `NSObject`.

I recommend to drop `NSCoding` completely and use `Codable` also for the class. Maybe you can resign the `NSObject` inheritance or even being a class.